# (Apple) GameplayKit State Machine implementation with SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, state-machine, gameplay-kit

I've read up on the GameplayKit State Machine and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/StateMachine.html)  explicitly mention Game UI as an example of usage. Im fully understanding the concept but I am unsure how to implement it while using SpriteKit.

Lets say I want 3 states. Menu, Gameplay and Game Over - All which display content to the SKScene. 
GameScene class extends SKScene. So it's impossible to turn GameScene into a state machine since we only can extend one class.

Should GameScene have a variable for a state machine with a reference to the SKScene, or is there a better solution? Earlier I've used protocols for state machines which makes it easy, but I'd like to try the functionality of GameplayKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Add the state machine variable in GameScene and initialise its starting state.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var stateMachine: GKStateMachine!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.stateMachine = GKStateMachine(states: [
            StartState(scene: self),
            PlayingState(scene: self),
            PausedState(scene: self),
        GameOverState(scene: self)
        ])

        self.stateMachine.enter(StartState.self)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        self.stateMachine.update(deltaTime: currentTime)
    }
}
```

Then initialise the states so they accept GameScene as input parameter.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class StartState: GKState {
    var scene: GameScene!

    init(scene: GameScene){
        super.init()

        self.scene = scene
    }

    override func isValidNextState(_ stateClass: Swift.AnyClass) -> Bool {
        return stateClass == PlayingState.self
    }

    override func updateWithDeltaTime(seconds: TimeInterval) {
        self.stateMachine?.enterState(PlayingState.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I found [this article](https://medium.com/swift-programming/build-tic-tac-toe-with-ai-using-swift-25c5cd3085c9#.6hyeh3v9j) explained `GKStateMachine` quite well and goes into detail about putting logic into each state.